# Error to use pandas.to_json() on Microsoft Databricks

Tags: json, pandas, databricks

Does anyone know if we have an alternative way to save pandas dataFrame as Json file on Microsoft Databricks?

I'm trying this:

```
dataframe.to_json('wasbs://<container>@<storage_account>.blob.core.windows.net/<file_name.json>', orient='records')
```

But it returns me "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:"

Also tried save locally, but returns the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using python , then you can do the following

```
from azure.storage.blob import (
    BlockBlobService
)
import pandas as pd
import io

output = io.StringIO()
head = ["col1" , "col2" , "col3"]
l = [[1 , 2 , 3],[4,5,6] , [8 , 7 , 9]]
df = pd.DataFrame (l , columns = head)
print df
output = df.to_json(orient='records')
print(output)

accountName = "***"
accountKey = "***"
containerName = "test1"
blobName = "test3.json"

blobService = BlockBlobService(account_name=accountName, account_key=accountKey)

blobService.create_blob_from_text('test1', 'OutFilePy.csv', output)
```

Alternatively you can mount the blobstorage and can use it further

Four mounting in python

```
dbutils.fs.mount(
  source = "wasbs://<your-container-name>@<your-storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net",
  mount_point = "/mnt/<mount-name>",
  extra_configs = {"<conf-key>":dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "<scope-name>", key = "<key-name>")})
```

and in scala

```
dbutils.fs.mount(
  source = "wasbs://<your-container-name>@<your-storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/<your-directory-name>",
  mountPoint = "/mnt/<mount-name>",
  extraConfigs = Map("<conf-key>" -> dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "<scope-name>", key = "<key-name>")))
```

and finally you can access mounted folder

```
data = pd.read_csv('/dbfs/mnt/mnt-name/opportunity.csv')
```

similarly

```
df.to_json('/dbfs/mnt/mnt-name/opportunity.json',orient='records')
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: yes, i'm using Python and Yes, it works! Ty @Mohit.

Comment: Glad to know it helped.